# NullType and TypeKind (OpenJDK)

Tags: java, types, wildcard

In the package `javax.lang.model.type` we have basic enum `TypeKind`.

```
public enum TypeKind {
BOOLEAN,
BYTE,
SHORT,
INT,
LONG,
CHAR,
FLOAT,
DOUBLE,
VOID,
NONE,
NULL,
ARRAY,
DECLARED,
ERROR,
TYPEVAR,
WILDCARD,
PACKAGE,
EXECUTABLE,
OTHER,
UNION;
public boolean More ...isPrimitive() {
        switch(this) {
        case BOOLEAN:
        case BYTE:
        case SHORT:
        case INT:
        case LONG:
        case CHAR:
        case FLOAT:
        case DOUBLE:
           return true;

        default:
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Interface `javax.lang.model.type.ReferenceType` inherited from `javax.lang.model.type.MirrorType`. `javax.lang.model.type.NullType` inherited from `javax.lang.model.type.ReferenceType`. Hence, basically, we have set of type, eight of this is primitive, two pseudo-types (`VOID`, `NONE`) and some other types, among which `NullType` and `WildcardType`.

**Question:** As i understood `null` expression is just implementation of `NullType` interface. Where i can find implementation of interface `NullType`, i.e. i want to know what's the `null` expression?

In the package `sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects` we have class `WildcardTypeImpl`. This class private fields:

```
private Type[] upperBounds;
private Type[] lowerBounds;
```

**Question** Is it true that if we using wildcard with extends `List<? extends Integer> ints;` we have that upperBounds will be implementation of NullType, and `lowerBounds=Integer`.

`WildcardType` interface doesnt inherited from interface `ReferenceType`. But if we using wildcard with super `List<? super Integer> ints` we can add elements to ints. I dont understand this.